# Form in jsp posts too much information

Tags: java, forms, spring, maven, http-post

I have a list with categories in my jsp, when i click a category, the list gets filled with the products of the categorie. When i click a product from that list, i need to add that product to another list in the jsp.
the problem i have is that a product from a category is added to the second list when i  clicked on a category, because when i post a category, the id of the productdto changes too...

this is the form:

```
  <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="item" >                  
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${item.getClass().name=='domain.Categorie'}">

      <form:form method="POST" action="shoppinglist.htm" modelAttribute="categoriedto"> 
      <form:input path="id" type="hidden" value="${item.id}" /> 
           <input type="submit" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="${item.categorieName}" class="productlistbtn">                                   
      </form:form>           
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
           <form:form method="POST" action="shoppinglist.htm" modelAttribute="productdto">                  
           <form:input path="id" type="hidden" value="${item.id}" /> 
           <input type="submit" height="150px" width="180px" alt="Submit" value="${item.description}" class="productlistbtn">                                   
           </form:form> 
  </c:otherwise>  
</c:choose>
          </c:forEach>
```

this is the post method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/shoppinglist"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showShoppinglistPage
(@ModelAttribute("categoriedto") CategorieDto categoriedto,
 @ModelAttribute("productdto") ProductDto productdto,Model model) 
{
    if(productdto.getId()!=0)
    {
    List<Product> producten=new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product p = categoryRepository.findProductBy(productdto.getId());
    producten.add(p);
    model.addAttribute("products", producten);
    }
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryRepository.findBy(categoriedto.getId()).getProducts());
   return "shoppinglist";
}
```

Comment: i guess posting multiple modelattributes isn't possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that you have two submit in form. so, It'll post all values. I think you need edit form again to resolve a problem.